# Angular i18n two projects in one | Need to change translation JSONs on before build

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have an angular community, which loads different translations depending on which URL the angular project is hosted.

Currently my structure looks like this with i18n:

[image]

As you see I added new JSONs, but I feel like this is not the way to go, as I have to refractor a lot more code.

It would be much better to create two directories and to tell angulat which path should be used, so the file names stay the same. Maybe with a build arg or something similar? Someone has an idea how to solve it?